# Sprites displaying fuzzy in Chrome 29.0.1547.57

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-sprites

When designing my site i noticed that under dark backgrounds all of the images I used as sprites turn out like this:

[image: blurry images with sprites]

I have tried multiple versions on PNGs and GIFs. IT works fine under firefox.

However, if i do not use sprites the image displays as:

[image: Clear images before sprites]

This is the same exact image just without any positioning tags.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The issue was my cache needed to be cleared!